# Including a property file with the Jar file in a single folder

Tags: java, eclipse, helios

I am creating a java application in Eclipse Helios.I have created a class in which i need to have data from the .properties file which i added in the folder containing the solution .Through this code i can accesss the value from the .properties file when i try to run it in Eclipse.

The code is:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
_url = prop.getProperty("url");
```

Through this code i am getting the correct value of the Url .

After this i have created an executable jar of my project .When i tried to execute the jar using command line then i got a FileNotFoundException ,means the jar is not able to locate the .properties file.

I have kept the .properties file in the same folder as of Jar file as we have the provision of editing the .properties file.

Since i started working in Java for only 4 days ,i am unable to figure out about where to place the .properties file and how to access it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

For jar try to use:

```
prop.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
```

if you call from static context use:

```
prop.load(YourClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
```

Comment: This is giving me error in getClassLoader stating cant resolved to a type or field

Comment: Sry i am unable to understand but its still saying that getclassloader() method is undefined,do i have to create a method with this name or sumthing else? thanks for the reply

Comment: I changed the line to : prop.load(FinalJavaScreenShare.class.getClassLoader().getResource("config.properties"));

Comment: now its showing wrror for load i.e The method load(Reader) in the type Properties is not applicable for the arguments (URL)

Comment: +1 for your efforts.  To the OP - note that the class-loader technique as shown here relates to resources on the run-time class-path of an application.  That class-path typically will include Jars but not loose resources in the same directories.  A resource in a Jar is an [tag:embedded-resource] & it seems like this one *should be* an embedded resource.  See the [embedded resource Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for a variant of that class loader method that returns an `URL` - though note it will not be possible to convert the `URL` to a valid file instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the class loader to get a resource.
See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
_url = prop.getProperty("url");
```

Comment: What is this classLoader here?

Comment: AClasssFromYourJar.class.getClassLoader()

Comment: done what you said .But then its giving error like this now i.e The method load(Reader) in the type Properties is not applicable for the arguments (URL)